# Inno Setup: WizardForm from an external form

Tags: inno-setup

I was trying to create an installer for my new project and used an external DLL to call a function to create a custom form. Instead of using the `WizardForm`, can I create the `WizardForm` from that custom form?

Here's the code I use to create that form:

```pascal
procedure NewFormCreate;
var
  rt: TTimer;
begin
  NewForm:= TForm.Create(nil);
  NewForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  CreateFormFromImage(NewForm.Handle, 'form.png');
  rt:= TTimer.create(nil);
  rt.OnTimer:= @WFProc;
  rt.Interval:= 1;
  rt.Enabled:= true;
  NewForm.Show;
  NewForm.Enabled:= False;
end;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `NewForm` to become the `WizardForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use your own implementation of the `WizardForm`.

You cannot. You can only modify the existing `WizardForm`. Maybe like this:

```pascal
CreateFormFromImage(WizardForm.Handle, 'form.png');
```

---

You can of course create and display your own form, and prevent the `WizardForm` from even displaying.

But it does not make sense. The Inno Setup is all about the `WizardForm`. If you do not want to use it, you do not need the Inno Setup at all. Build your custom installer in Delphi (if that's your preferred IDE).

---

Maybe you should explain us what do you really want to achieve. It's quite probable that you have an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0):

Is your X problem creating an installer with irregular shape?

Instead of scripting everything manually you can use **Graphical Installer for Inno Setup** (http://graphical-installer.com/) and achieve something like this in few minutes:

[image: Graphical Installer with irregular shape]

If you use Delphi you can use **RAD & Installer** (http://rad-installer.com/) to create the Inno Setup installers directly from RAD Studio IDE.

Sorry for little self promo :)